# Error when passing None instead of Series to function

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a module `fi` with the following classes defined:

```
class CashFlows(Asset):

   def __init__(self, amounts : pandas.Series, probabilities : pandas.Series = None):
       amounts = Asset.to_cash_flows()

       if probabilities is None:
           probabilities = pandas.Series([1]*len(amounts), index=amounts.index)
```

I then have another class `Bond(fi.Asset)` with this method within it, which is where `CashFlows` is being called:

```
def to_cash_flows(self, notional : float = 100.0) -> fi.asset.CashFlows:
    #Bunch of stuff here which is not related
    series = pandas.Series(list_of_data, indices_of_data)
    return fi.CashFlows(series)
```

I get the error `obiwan.ObiwanError:__init__(probabilities) is None but should be <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`, but I thought I was addressing the possibility of such an Error with the `if` statement. `obiwan` is just a Python type-checking package that I am using during Unit-Testing.

Thank You

Comment: Why do you give it a type declaration and then complain when there is a complaint that it doesn't match the type declaration?

Comment: @PatrickMaupin The type declaration is required as part of testing. However, I am under the impression that I have taken care of the one case when it doesn't match the type and is in fact a `None`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [obiwan PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/obiwan/1.0.2):

You can specify alternative constraint types using sets:

```
def example5(x: {int,float}):
    ...
```

Taking that at face value, it would seem you should replace:

```
probabilities : pandas.Series = None
```

with:

```
probabilities : {pandas.Series, type(None)} = None
```

This will tell obiwan that None is an acceptable value for the parameter.

obiwan is not actually looking *into* the function itself and doesn't care about the `if` statement that compares the parameter to None.  It is only looking at the function declaration.